# Store task info in database

Tags: database, database-design, language-agnostic

Let's say I have a database where I store the users tasks.

To simplify lets say that a task has:

- id
- status (New, To do, In progress, Done, Rejected)
- description
- owner/creator

Now what I want to achieve is when a user finishes a task - makes it Done or Rejected, I want the user to provide some info about that state change. I imagine a popup with two fields: one to choose from Done/Rejected statuses and a textfield area to fill in the reason if you will.

The problem I have here is: how do I store the information about the task completion?

My idea is to create a table like `task_completions` which will have:

- id
- task_id
- comment (varchar or whatever)

Now the thing is: when I load a task for a user from the database and I see it's completed (again, Done or Rejected) I need to load the information about the task completion. So it would result in two API calls:

- get task
- get task_completion, where `task_completion.task_id == task_id`

There's of course another way - I can add a task_completion field to my `task` table. And of course make it nullable, since it won't be filled with anything until the task is completed. And then I won't have to make two API calls, since when using something like Django serializers (or something like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)), I will be able to "expand" the `task_completion` field from just a plain number (id from `task_completion`) column to a full nested JSON with information about the completion (id, task_id, comment) - I just have to call `get task`. And then I don't even have to provide the `task_id` field in the `task_completion` table.

So summing up, I think that I have 3 choices:

- `task` and `task_completion` tables, where `task_completion` table contains the `task_id` column - two API calls
- `task` and `task_completion` tables, where `task` table contains `task_completion_id` column - one API call if I do it right
- `task` and `task_completion` tables, where `task` table contains `task_completion_id` column and `task_completion` table contains a `task_id` column - still one API call I guess - but does it make sens to have both of those columns in those tables?

Comment: Can't you just put a nullable `comment` column on your `task` table?

Comment: I can, but if I would want to extend that comment to let's say contain the person that closed the task or anything else, this would create a mess in `task` table

Comment: Fair point. Can a task be reopened or can be only one completion per task?

Comment: I am kinda mimicking Jira's behavior, so the task could potentially be reopened

Comment: The firs choice (`task_completion` table with `task_id` column referencing `task` table is more correct, since you can have more than one completion for each `task`. But I suggest, instead, some kind of `task_status_history` table, since you will probably want a history of the changes. I don't really know django, so I can't comment about the number of api calls but, unless it is extremely expensive, it doesn't matter if it is one or two.

Comment: That's what I thought. I mean, it's not really DJango specific I guess, the database query will have to be done - table `task` contains a `task_completion_id` and it hast to query the `task_completion` table for a row, but it's done on backend, not on separate API calls from frontend, something like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related. That aside, I guess your suggestion is correct, that was my first instinct as well. I will wait, maybe someone can answer my question from the number of calls perspective, but thank you for your input!

Comment: If your solution depends on the number of calls perspective, you should ask yourself whether your app should run on a desktop or on a smartphone. Smartphones usually have a bigger ping so it's generally better to have the least calls. In case of a desktop, it doesn't matter - except if you'd like your app to be energy efficient. Then you'll prefer a single call.

Comment: It's a desktop web app, but even when efficiency doesn't matter then still - one async call is easier to maintain that 2-3 calls - mess in code etc.